# Firebase simple login only throws 'INVALID_EMAIL' error

Tags: error-handling, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

first question on stackoverflow, so please tell me if my info is insufficient. Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to implement a firebase-simple-login, but the only error type I am getting is 'INVALID EMAIL' on the signIn function. If I enter an incorrect password with an existing email it still throws invalid e-mail.

```
$scope.signIn = function() {
        $rootScope.auth.$login('password', {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        }).then(function(user) {
            console.log("user has email " + user.email);
        }, function(error) {
            if (error = 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
                console.log('email invalid or not signed up');
            } else if (error = 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
                console.log('invalid password');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };
```

For extra reference; the html with the corresponding form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" ng-model="email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="signIn()">Sign in</button>
```

I can't seem to find anything useful on error types in the firebase docs, so I hope you can help.

CreateUser is invoked as such:

```
 $scope.signUp = function() {
        $rootScope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function(error,user) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('User Id: ' + user.uid + ', Email: ' + user.email);
            }
        }).then(function(){
            $rootScope.auth.$login('password', {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: You probably need to create the user first using [createUser](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html)? If not, we'll need to see what you're inputting into the login method.

Comment: Have you verified that $scope.email is properly defined when .login() is invoked?

Comment: @Kato Thank you very much for replying. I create the user via createUser, and it seems to work fine. I can log existing users in and I can create new users. I've added createUser as I use it to the question.

Comment: @RobDiMarco Thank you very much for replying. I'm not sure I understand (I'm a beginner). Is adding 'email' to the ng-model and $scope.email in the signIn function not sufficient? How would I define it beforehand?

Comment: @jimbo just try a console.log($scope.email) right before calling $login() and see what it contains.

Comment: @Kato $scope.email contains the correct email. I think I am explaining it wrong, sorry about that. The $login()/$createUser() seem to be working fine. My problem is that of the error ID's explained at Login error IDs explained on the [firebase page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) (at the bottom) only 'INVALID EMAIL' is being returned. The 'INVALID_PASSWORD' as show above for instance, gives me nothing. It feels very much like I'm getting something very basic wrong, but I can't get at it. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't see the error INVALID_PASSWORD when you enter an invalid password, but instead get an error for INVALID_EMAIL?

Comment: @Kato I've posted my answer, code is working fine now. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found after inspecting the error function further. It seems you need to go into the error object, to `error.code` in stead of just `error`, as well as using the operator `===` instead of `=`. I had lifted the `$login()` straight from the firebase docs, but I might have mixed some things up in the process. Anyway, here's the working code.

```
function(error) {
            if (error.code === 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
                console.log('email invalid or not signed up');
            } else if (error.code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
                console.log('invalid password');
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! Glad you sorted it. Sorry I didn't spot that earlier.

Comment: No problem @Kato. It seems it is not documented in this way (not anywhere I can find at least) and it seems unusual that going into the error object is necessary. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Firebase provided error messages instead of if clause.

```
function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log(error_code.message)
  }
}
```